# Find gaps in a sequence of Strings

Tags: python

I have got a sequence of strings - `0000001, 0000002, 0000003....` upto 2 million. They are not contiguous. Meaning there are gaps. Say after 0000003 the next string might be 0000006. I need to find out all these gaps. In the above case (0000004, 0000005).

This is what I have done so far -

```
gaps  = list()
total = len(curr_ids)

for i in range(total):
    tmp_id = '%s' %(str(i).zfill(7))
    if tmp_id in curr_ids:
        continue
    else:
        gaps.append(tmp_id)
return gaps
```

But as you would have guessed, this is slow since I am using `list`. If I use a `dict`, to pre-populate curr_ids it'll be faster. But what's the complexity to populating a hash-table? What's the fastest way to do this.

Comment: Although they are not contiguous, are they in order?

Comment: @khachik, @paul yes input is sorted... In anycase I can get it sorted if it improves overall performance...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could sort the list of ids and then step through it once only:

```
def find_gaps(ids):
    """Generate the gaps in the list of ids."""
    j = 1
    for id_i in sorted(ids):
        while True:
            id_j = '%07d' % j
            j += 1
            if id_j >= id_i:
                break
            yield id_j

>>> list(find_gaps(["0000001", "0000003", "0000006"]))
['0000002', '0000004', '0000005']
```

If the input list is already in order, then you can avoid the `sorted` (though it does little harm: Python's [adaptive mergesort](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listsort.txt) is O(*n*) if the list is already sorted).

Answer (score 3):

For storing sequence of 2 millions ints you can use [bitarray](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/). Here each bit means one integer (the integer of that index in bitarray). Example code:

```
gaps = []
# bitarray is 0 based
a = bitarray.bitarray(total + 1)
a.setall(False)
for sid in curr_ids:
    a[int(sid)] = True
for i in range(1, total):
    if not a[i]:
        gaps.append('%07d' %(i))
return gaps
```

Answer (score 1):

```
seq = *the sequence of strings*
n = 2000000

gaps = set(str(i).zfill(7) for i in range(1,n+1)) - set(seq)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest take it int rather than string for processing and then making it a string again in output

```
j=0
n=2000000
#create a list of int number from your string
foo = [i for i in range(n)]
#creating gaps
foo.remove(1)
foo.remove(50)
while j<n:
    for i in foo:
        if i>j:
            print '%07d'%j
            j+=1
        j+=1
```