# How to find the smallest missing numbers from a list without using inbuilt functions or modules

Tags: python, list

Here is my list:

```
List = [[1,2,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5,7], [1,4,5,6], [2,3,5], [1,2,3]]
```

From this how to find all the smallest missing numbers?

**Edit:**

- The "smallest missing number" is the first integer (> 0) that is not in the list.
- The expected output for the example input is 3, 6, 2, 1 and 4.
- The input lists are always sorted.

Comment: *missing number*? *mission number*? What is it?

Comment: Please show the code that you've tried already. Also, it's not clear exactly what the problem is here...

Comment: *without any python inbuild functions* -- Does that mean no `for` loops, no addition and no Python?

Comment: Sorry for the Spelling Mistake @YuHao

Comment: What is your expected output?  Give an example.

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment to keep you busy for a while. In a real-life situation you'd never avoid built-in functions for tasks like this.

Comment: Will the lists always be sorted? And what if a list doesn't contain the `1`. Would `1` be the solution?

Comment: @Falko  Yeah i accept that, but i mean for range,sort like. and i hope you guys can understand the problem by the below answer :)

Comment: Wrong tag ! is not python !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach without any built-in functions:

```
Lists = [[1,2,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5,7],[1,4,5,6]]

for List in Lists:
    i = 1
    while i <= List[-1] + 1:
        if i in List:
            i += 1
        else:
            break
    print i
```

Basically it processes each `List` separately (is that what you want?). It iterates a counter `i` starting at `1` (assuming you look for integers > 0) and stops, as soon as `List` doesn't contain `i`.

Output:

```
3
6
2
```

Comment: Yeah... this is what i am looking for. Great!

Comment: Why not `i = List[0]` instead of hardcoding `1` to work for any sublist?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: If I understand correctly, the expected output might be `1`, if `1` is not in the list. With `i = List[0]` you'd miss that on a list like, e.g., `[2, 3, 5]`.

Comment: You might be right based on the edit, if that is the case the question is a lot simpler

Answer (score 1):

If the sublists are already sorted like you input, just compare the previous to the current element, if the prev +1 is not equal to the current ele add prev + 1 to the output list:

```
List = [[1, 2, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7], [1, 4, 5, 6]]
out = []
for sub in List:
    prev = sub[0]
    for  ele in sub[1:]:
        if prev + 1 != ele:
            out.append(prev +1)
            break
        prev = ele
print(out)
[3, 6, 2]
```

It will work for any sublists that are ordered not just lists starting with 1:

```
List = [[3, 4, 5,7], [10,13,14,15], [100,101,104,105]]
```

Output:

```
[6, 11, 102]
```

And without slicing:

```
out = []
for sub in List:
    prev = sub[0]
    i = 0
    for ele in sub:
        if i == 0:
            i += 1
            continue
        if prev + 1 != ele:
            out.append(prev +1)
            break
        prev = ele
print(out)
```

If you always want to find the first missing number starting at `1` and can have 0 or negative numbers, only check each ele and increase `i` if the ele is > 0:

```
out = []
for sub in Lists:
    i = 1
    for ele in sub:
        if ele > 0:
            if ele != i:
                out.append(i)
                break
            i += 1
print(out)
```

That means at worst you do a single pass over each sublist as opposed to `O(n^2)` approach using `in`

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16974075/3419103):

```
List = [[1,2,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5,7],[1,4,5,6]]
print [sorted(set(range(1,max(l)+2)).difference(l))[0] for l in List]
```

Output:

```
[3, 6, 2]
```

Sure, this approach uses built-in functions. But you can start from here and break it down by replacing forbidden functions by your own implementations.

Comment: code looking good and thanks, i still thinking about the actual code like writing in c language :)