# How do I find missing number sequences in Python through Gap Analysis?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numbers, sequence, analysis

```
Title 1            Title 2
DKTM 00001          DKTM 00008
DKTM 00009          DKTM 00017
DKTM 00029          DKTM 00038
DKTM 00050          DKTM 00061
DKTM 00062          DKTM 00073
```

Thanks for everyone who continued to read. My dilemma is that I have a CSV with missing rows of data. There are two columns, One starting with a row of numbers (Like DKTM00001) and ending with a row (DKTM000008) as stated
The columns repeat like this for the numbers, but in some cases, a row of numbers end up missing (Stated above). I want to find those row of missing numbers and output them to the screen. (I would ask to put them to a output file, but I want to do this, to teach myself Python.)

An example of the desired output:

```
DKTM 00018     DKTM 00028
DKTM 00039     DKTM 00049
```

Thank you in advance! I'm relatively new to Python 3.6.2, so I thought this would be a good exercise. Guess I bit off more than I can chew. I utilized this explanation as a basis([Efficient way to find missing elements in an integer sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974047/efficient-way-to-find-missing-elements-in-an-integer-sequence)), but downshift's method helped me with the desired output a lot more.

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? This is not a code-writing service

Comment: @SomeNewPythonGuy: To get a proper answer you should produce a reproducible version of your code.

Comment: My apologies gentleman. I looked at the link for a general idea as to how I wanted the code to work, but got lost as the code needed a different output. I'm so sorry if I was seeming like I wanted a free code for nothing. I didn't want to give that impression.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may help you get started.

I'm not too clear on the content layout of your `csv` file (or which version of python you are using), but using a `csv` file with this content:

```
DKTM00001,DKTM00009
DKTM00002,DKTM00010
DKTM00003,DKTM00011

DKTM00005,DKTM00013
DKTM00006,DKTM00014

DKTM00008,DKTM00016
```

we can read the file using the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for line, row in enumerate(reader, 1):
        if not row:
            print 'line:', line, 'contents:', row
```

Output:

```
line: 4 contents: []
line: 7 contents: []
```

The [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function is useful in this situation since we want to count rows and print which lines are empty. Here I've passed `1` as the `start` parameter to `enumerate` to offset the line count starting from `1` instead of the default `0`.

Modify as needed for your specific Python version. Feel free to comment for any clarification or modification.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, downshift! Yes it's a great step. I'm using Python 3.6.2. I'm so sorry for not displaying my code. I'll find my original code shortly if I can. But yes, the code was supposed to do something along the lines of..............                                                                                     
 Title 1     Title 2                                                                           DKTM00013,DKTM00024                                                                                                            For the the lines of codes that are missing

Comment: You're very welcome, it would help if you included any code or sample inputs and expected outputs so we can compose an better solution. Feel free to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46164858/edit) and update your question with any more information (consider using the formatting tools in the question form, as comments lack formatting) so we can create a better solution. and thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Thank you! I updated my original comment, so as to reflect the changes you've mentioned. Hope that helps! And again, thank you so much!