# Get next number from a list of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numbers

I have a list of numbers(let's say `list_num = []`) from 0 to x. It may not contain all the numbers between 0 and x (ie, skipping say 4 and 7), but I don't know.

I want to get the first missing number from the list or, if none are missing, I want to get the next number after ( something like: `len(list_num)` <- no +1 because the list starts at 0).

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718315/how-to-find-a-missing-number-from-a-list/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974047/efficient-way-to-find-missing-elements-in-an-integer-sequence), but they are both slightly different

How can I do this Python 3? I don't mind using some APIs.

Comment: Can I ask why this was downvoted?

Comment: Lack of effort on your part. Show what you've tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: This can be done using simple `for` loops. Put in some effort?

Comment: @JJJ I'll add the things, i've tried

Comment: Better add explicit examples. That would make it clearer and make it easier for us to test our code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the first item matching the condition. If none, you need `x+1`

```
try:
    first_value = next(val for val in range(x) if val not in list_sum)
except StopIteration:
    first_value = x+1
```

Comment: Thanks. This is simple and short

Answer (score 1):

You could make it with sets:

```
>>> lst = set([1,2,3,4,5,9,11,14])
>>> set(range(0, max(lst))).difference(lst)
{0, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 13}
```

or list comprehensions:

```
>>> lst = set([1,2,3,4,5,9,11,14])
>>> allNumbers = list(range(0, max(lst)))
>>> [x for x in allNumbers if x not in lst]
[0, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 13]
```