# How to find missing and additional values in Tuple without using Set in Python?

Tags: python, logic

How to find Missing and additional values in Tuple without using Set.

For eg.,

```
tuple1= ("apple", "banana", "cherry")
tuple2= ("apple", "banana", "mango")
```

Missing Value: Cherry 
Additional Value: Mango

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficient way to find missing elements in an integer sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16974047/608639). Different container, same technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list-comprehensions:

```
tuple1= ("apple", "banana", "cherry")
tuple2= ("apple", "banana", "mango")

# Missing:
print([x for x in tuple1 if x not in tuple2]) # ['cherry']

# Additional: 
print([x for x in tuple2 if x not in tuple1]) # ['mango']
```